# Review queues were throwing 500 server errors

Tags: bug, review, 500-server-error

For a few minutes, all /review pages across all sites seemed to result in the "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" server error page.

This was confirmed by [multiple](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53304577#53304577) [users](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53304583#53304583) in chat and a [comment on this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371110/review-queues-are-throwing-500-server-errors#comment1238652_371110).  However, it seems to be fixed now.

Example links that were broken:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/close
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats
- https://law.stackexchange.com/review

Comment: Work for me. Might be just one of the servers acting up so not really definitive.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek and...just like that, it's fixed for me, too.  Despite multiple other people reporting the same issue.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I found the Math one wasn't working just a few minutes ago, but it's working properly now. Assuming the other sites are also now working, this seems to have been a rather short-term problem.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect that it was temporary.

Comment: I had an error trying to approve a suggested edit 56 minutes ago on SO (I wasn't in the review queue) and then an error when trying to delete a low-quality post now on SOpt. Both worked after refreshing the page and trying again. Not sure if it is related. Tried to reproduce with the Developer Tools open but it didn't happen again.

Comment: Same on [https://crafts.stackexchange.com/review](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/review) (at the time - all is good now).